# DateTime as OutputClaim from a RestfulProvider technical profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a technical profile that is attempting to use a datetime as an output claim.

I have defined a claim called Dob

```
<ClaimType Id="Dob">
    <DisplayName>Dob</DisplayName>
    <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Here is the tecnical profile that uses it:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="UserApi-GetUserDob">
  <DisplayName>Get User Dob From Api</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">URL-HERE</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Username" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Dob"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I have done a sample request and here is the format of the Dob field in the API

```
{
    "Dob": "1989-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Using the B2C User Journey Player i have found that the error that is being raised is the following:

Exception:

A self-asserted send response has failed with reason 'Internal Server Error'.

So my question is do i have the datetime in the correct format for B2C to consume it?

Comment: The date/time format is valid. (Note a date/time claim is issued as an epoch time in the ID token so dates before 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC will be issued as a negative numeric value.) Is this technical profile being invoked as a validation technical profile? Is the REST API returning an error response?

Comment: Yes the technical profile is being invoked as a validation technical profile. No the REST API is not returning an error.

Comment: Are you only intending to add the "Dob" claim to the claim set to be issued for the current user journey? If so, then it would be better if you invoke the REST API technical profile from an orchestration step rather than from another technical profile.

Answer (score 0):

According to [TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd), there are the following data types:

```
boolean
date
int
long
string
stringCollection
```

Try using `date`.

---

BTW, you can wire up VS Code to give you this data "inline":

[image: data types screenshot]